# App crashs when re-activating from App-List

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, mvvmcross, reload

My WP8-App runs with Xamarin and MvvmCross.

When I open my app normal and then go back via the start-button/windows-button on my device and try to re-open my app through the app-list, my app crashs with the following exception:

```
{Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Unable to find incoming MvxViewModelRequest
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneViewsContainer.GetRequestFromXamlUri(Uri viewUri)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneExtensionMethods.LoadViewModel(IMvxPhoneView phoneView, Uri navigationUri, IMvxBundle savedStateBundle)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneExtensionMethods.<>c__DisplayClass1.<OnViewCreate>b__0()
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate(IMvxView view, Func`1 viewModelLoader)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate(IMvxPhoneView phoneView, Uri navigationUri, IMvxBundle savedStateBundle)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhonePage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at MyApp.MyNamespace.Views.BasePage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedToX(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated(Object content, Uri uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean isNavigationInitiator, IPhoneApplicationPage existingContentPage, IPhoneApplicationPage newContentPage)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject content, NavigationMode mode)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)}
```

This happens on every page (also static-pages which just shows some text).

When I try to reload my app through the "last-opened-app" list (long tap on back-button on my device) everything works fine, the last page is displayed and no exception occurd.

If you need more information, just ask for it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer (at least for me). Just look at the following link: http://www.codecoding.com/fast-app-switching-and-mvvmcross-how-to-make-it-work/

This solved my problem

Comment: Were you able to implement this fix in a Windows Phone 8.1 environment (not 8.0)? Some parts of the code don't work in 8.1 (PhoneApplicationService, RootFrame, for example)